# Why My multiple email sending system is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, email

I am trying to send Email who are listed in my Userprofiles table and i have also added 2 columns like PhoneNo and Email. And also added values in this table. My wish is to send email these listed persons at a time. Now it is sending only one mail at a time. I have tried this code but it is not working. Please Help..

```
    public ActionResult SendEmail(string address, string subject, string message)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var v = (from e in db.todaySalesReport()
                    select e).SingleOrDefault();

            var ctx = new UsersContext();
            string from = "";
            foreach (var i in ctx.UserProfiles.ToList())
            {
                address = i.Email;
                //MailAddress addr = new MailAddress();
                using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, address))
                {

                        mail.To.Add(i.Email);
                        mail.Subject = "Total Sales Report for today";

                        mail.Body = "Total sales" + v.qty.ToString() + "Peices.";

                        mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

                        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                        NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(from, "");

                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                        smtp.Credentials = networkCredential;

                        smtp.Port = 587;


                        smtp.Send(mail);

                        ViewBag.Message = "Sent";

                        return View("Index", address);

                    }
                }
            }


        else
        {

            return View();

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: You looking  for something like marketing email?

Comment: A return inside the loop? That will terminate the loop immediatelly

Comment: yes..something like that.

Comment: So should use those API, like [CampaignMonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are returning your view inside your foreach loop. Take this code out of the foreach loop:

```
return View("Index", address);
```

It should be like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var v = (from e in db.todaySalesReport()
                select e).SingleOrDefault();

        var ctx = new UsersContext();
        string from = "";
        foreach (var i in ctx.UserProfiles.ToList())
        {
            address = i.Email;
            //MailAddress addr = new MailAddress();
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, address))
            {

                    mail.To.Add(i.Email);
                    mail.Subject = "Total Sales Report for today";

                    mail.Body = "Total sales" + v.qty.ToString() + "Peices.";

                    mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(from, "");

                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                    smtp.Credentials = networkCredential;

                    smtp.Port = 587;


                    smtp.Send(mail);

                    ViewBag.Message = "Sent";



             }
       }
     return View("Index", address);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this

```
 return View("Index", address);
```

dangling at the end of your loop. Move it out of the loop and it should be fine.